# Whatsapp images lost

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, whatsapp-messenger

So my Samsung S3 mini kept reminding me that my storage is running out and i probably tempered around with the storage but do not remember deleting my entire whatsapp images folder and videos folder. Any clue on how i can get this back or what may have happened? I definitely did not delete any folders but only whatsapp images and videos folder have disappeared!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the "do not remember deleting my entire whatsapp images folder and videos folder." i believe you have only cleared the cache memmory of your whats-app application from the application manager.

If yes/no you can still view the images/videos in the Phone Memmory/SD-Card>
WhatsApp>Media>WhatsApp images/WhatsApp Video

Comment: I realised I didn't have a SD card in my phone until I put  it in yesterday. I went to see if I could find photos on the device on computer, and couldn't see them anywhere. Just strange because I updated Whatsapp the same evening it happened. Can it be because of new version Whatsapp update??

Comment: If you don't have the SD-Card then look in your Phone memory(in Android 4.1 its displayed as sdCard0 ). As that is the default place where the apps are stored.As far as the update is concerned an update is on the functionality side and does not remove any images,videos(solves bugs if any). Until and unless you remove the app manually there will be the Whats App folder with all the content in them.